# ASP MVC http.post calling Action to Controller with angular not working

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

So I apologize from the start that I am very new to AngularJS.

So what I am trying to do is pass back my model in my view back to my controller. I tried searching all over the internet with no luck.

Here is what I have right now:

```
(function() {
    var mod = angular.module('branding', []);

    mod.controller('BrandingController', ['$scope', '$http', function(brandModel) {
        brandModel.model = dataModel.Views;
        brandModel.SelectedName = "a";
        brandModel.SelectedDescription = "s";
        brandModel.SelectedIsBuiltIn = true;

        brandModel.selectItem = function(view) {
            brandModel.SelectedName = view.Name;
            brandModel.SelectedDescription = view.Description;
            brandModel.SelectedIsBuiltIn = view.IsBuiltIn;

        };
        brandModel.clearText = function() {
            brandModel.SelectedName = "";
            brandModel.SelectedDescription = "";
            brandModel.SelectedIsBuiltIn = "";
        };

        brandModel.update = function($http) {
            brandModel.apply(function() {
            $http.post("@Url.Action("SaveBranding","AirlineConfig")");
            //.success and .fail never are triggered when implemented 
            });
        };
    }]); 
})();
```

My Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveBranding(BrandingViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View("Branding", viewModel);
    }
```

I am able to trigger the call of update no problem but I see nothing at all from the http.post call.

I have tried just a call directly to the server via a post and to a direct path and that didnt work either.

Comment: What does the network request/response look like in the debug console for `/AirlineConfig/SaveBranding`?

Comment: Actually the network tab showed nothing but the console did show this:

Unable to get property 'post' of undefined or null reference

Comment: If this angular code is in a separate js file then it will not properly parse and render the Razor `@Url.Action()` and will likely result in a javascript error.

Comment: You're missing $http in the controller function...you just have it in the dependency list.

Comment: @Jasen This is all in one file.

Comment: @BradBarber isnt they way i have it in the controller declaration correct?

Comment: mod.controller('BrandingController', ['$scope', '$http', function(brandModel) {... should be mod.controller('BrandingController', ['$scope', '$http', function(brandMode, $http) {

Comment: I think you also need remove $http from the update function: brandModel.update = function() {

Comment: @BradBarber so i have made that change and it still doesnt work. I get the same error. "Unable to get property 'post' of undefined or null reference at brandModel.update" ...

Comment: You made the second change as well where $http was getting redefined in the update function?

Comment: @BradBarber you were right. I needed to remove my $http in the update function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add property:

```
mod.controller('BrandingController', ['$scope', '$http', function(brandModel, $http) {
```

and invoke like that:

```
 brandModel.update = function() {
            $http.post("@Url.Action("SaveBranding","AirlineConfig")", brandModel.model);
            //.success and .fail never are triggered when implemented 
        };
```

Where your brandModel.model is BrandingViewModel.

Comment: I have change my script to be this and i still get a TypeError: Unable to get property 'post' of undefined or null reference

Comment: In the end i needed to remove the $http in the update function

Comment: Ooo, Sorry I mad a mistake. Remove $http from 'brandModel.update = function($http) {'

Comment: now when I pass the model back to the controller, do i need to convert it back into the viewmodel type?

Comment: You need pass an object with the same fields as the viewmodel. If your viewmodel has a property like 'public Name {get;set;}' you should pass javascript object with 'Name' field.

Comment: Ok. I understand. If I get stuck I will post another question.